# What is the meaning of 地道 in this context?

Tags: word-usage

it usually means "steady; honest; sober; straightforward"  but it appears to have a different meaning in the following sentence:

> **地道**な勉学にはあまり向かなかった、性格が明るく、多くの人に好かれた。

Source: it is a novel from Mr Haruki Murakami and it is about a person who is kind, is strong in sports, but has not very good results at school.

Remark: response edited due to the remark of Ben

Comment: `地道な勉学にはあまり向かなかった、性格が明るく...` <-- You sure you copied it correctly? Is it not 地道な勉学にはあまり向かなかった**が** 、性格が明るく... or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage in the above sentence is the usual meaning of jimichi:

[Goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E5%9C%B0%E9%81%93/m1u/):

> 手堅く着実に物事をすること。地味でまじめなこと。また、そのさま。「地道な努力をする」「地道に働く」

[WWWJDIC](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%C3%CF%C6%BB):

> 地道 【じみち】 (adj-na,n) steady; honest; sober; straightforward;

It just means that he wasn't good at studying, in the sense of regularly getting to work on something.